# angular css scrollbox not working on div with ng-for of components list

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm working with Angular7 and I have a list of components inside a div. I need to implement top and bottom shadow.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="product_list_content scrollbox" id="scroll_style">
      <app-product-detail *ngFor="let product of productList" [product]="product" style="height: 12%; min-height: 12%;" (editProd)="openEditProduct(productModal, $event)"></app-product-detail>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrollbox {
    overflow: auto;
    background: /* Shadow covers */
    linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%, /* Shadows */
    radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(50% 100%, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
    background: /* Shadow covers */
    linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%, /* Shadows */
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;
    /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
    background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
  }
```

Basically the shadow is not shown if the product-detail component is at the shadow place.

Thanks for any help! stay safe!